# Ошибка при подключении собственной библиотеки

Tags: c#, unity3d

Написал библиотеку классов с названием `Novel`. Сбилдил добавил dll в основной проект Unity. Получаю ошибку, что не удаётся найти его.

[image]

А при этом в `Visual Studio` нету ошибок.

[image]

Пробую перезагрузить проект и ошибка в редакторе остается,  а в самом проекте нету ссылки.

---

*В чём моя ошибка и как его исправить?*

Comment: под какой фреймворк у вас библиотека и под какой у вас unity?

Comment: библиотека под .NET

Comment: дотнетов много, и у каждого ещё свои версии есть и не все дотнеты между собой совместимы.

Comment: тоесть попробовать поменять версию .Net?

Comment: 1) Понять какая из версий используется в Unity 2) Использовать такую же версию для своей либы